# Live clock with java script, that shows the actual seconds minutes and hours

Tags: javascript, html, css, clock

I am trying to make a clock in java script to show the actual time in real time  but it isn't working for some reason.. I also need there to be buttons and the buttons to change to colour of the clock.

Any help will be very appreciated.

```
<html>


<head>


<title>    Clock II & III   </title>

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clock.css">


            <script type = "text/javascript">

                function renderTime() {

            var currentTime() = new Date(); 
            var diem = "AM"
            var h = currentTime.getHours();
            var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
            var s = currentTime.getSeconds();


            if (h ==0){
                h = 12
            }   else if (h>12) {
                h = h - 12; 
                diem = "PM";

            }

            if (h<10){
                h = "0" + h;

            }

            if (m<10){
                m = "0" + m;

            }

            if (s<10){
                s = "0" + s;

            }


            var myClock = document.getElementById('clockdisplay')
            myClock.textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + diem; 
            myClock.innerText = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + diem; 
            setTimeout('renderTime()',1000);
            }


            renderTime(); 
            </script>


</head>


<body>



<div id = "clockdisplay" class = "clockStyle">      
22:23PM
</div>



<body>



</html>


#clockdisplay {

    background-color:#000;
    border:#999 2px inset;
    padding:6px;
    color:#0FF;
    font-family:"Ariel Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    display:inline;

}
```

Comment: Have you googled for it? http://www.webestools.com/ftp/ybouane/scripts_tutorials/javascript/date_time/date_time.html

Comment: What is the problem with it.  Is it not executing the function, is the function executing but not updating the values properly?

Comment: if the code above is how you have it then put the css inside a style tag within the head elements for starters

Comment: Working js: http://jsfiddle.net/ygkn99tm/ i'll leave the button functions as an exercise for the OP.

Comment: If you state more clearly what the problem is, it is a lot easier to help you. Posting any error messages you get (JavaScript errors are found in the console, reached by right-clicking the page, choosing 'inspect element' and then clicking 'console' in most browsers) and including both what it does and what it should do if it does something unexpected will both increase the odds of getting a clearer answer in less time.

Comment: It will also (help to) avoid getting downvotes (like this post - it now has a score of -2).

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few syntax errors.
Try to change:

`var currentTime() = new Date();` to `var currentTime = new Date();` and

`setTimeout('renderTime()',1000);` to `setTimeout(renderTime,1000);`

You have some missing semicolons as well, but these 2 changes will make it work, as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fj8v32f9/).

Comment: Some response would have been nice.